# Agda Expr data type

Tags: agda

I am trying to define an expression data type in Agda.
The idea is simple; given the following definition

```
data Expr : N -> Set where
   Val : N -> Expr n
   Add : Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n
   Var : Fin n -> Expr n
   Let : Expr n -> Expr (succ n) -> Expr n
```

where `Fin` is the well known finite set defined by Agda's builtin library. However, when I implement this, for the Add, Var and Let, it does not recognize `n`. This seems a bit weird, since it should be able to deduct that it is some natural number. How do I fix this?

I have tried to make it implicit by adding `{n : Nat}`, but I am not sure whether that is the correct way to deal with it.

Comment: It is the correct way. Alternatively you could declare `variable n : N`  to have it introduced automatically whenever the binding site is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, all constructors target the expression `n`, so you can turn your Catholic index into a Protestant index (to the left of the colon). This puts `n` in scope for the body of the declaration.

```
open import Data.Nat.Base renaming (ℕ to N; suc to succ)
open import Data.Fin

data Expr (n : N) : Set where
   Val : N -> Expr n
   Add : Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n
   Var : Fin n -> Expr n
   Let : Expr n -> Expr (succ n) -> Expr n
```